# How to determine if current culture/locale uses am/pm or 24-hour time?

Tags: .net, time

I need to determine if the current culture/locale is set to use am/pm time or 24-hour time.

At first I thought I could do this:

```
bool time24Hour = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.AMDesignator == "";
```

But then I read the comments on the last answer on this thread [Get just the hour of day from DateTime using either 12 or 24 hour format as defined by the current culture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015040/get-just-the-hour-of-day-from-datetime-using-either-12-or-24-hour-format-as-defin) which seems to imply this won't work.

I guess I could format an arbitrary time, and then analyze the results, but surely there's a simplier way?

EDIT:

See also my comment below - I just want to determine which one of two pre-formatted constant strings containing lists of hours I should select, and hope to avoid a lot of unnecessary contortions - I just need a yes/no answer as to whether this is an am/pm culture or a 24-hour culture.

The program is a WinForms program, if that is of any help.

Comment: I need to select one of two pre-generated and constant lists of hours, either "9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17" or "9 10 11 12 1 2 3 4 5", depending on the culture. I'm hoping it isn't necessary to go through a lot of contortions involving DateTime and formatting and so on.

Comment: First, you should edit your question to include that information. Second, are you using Windows Forms? Web Forms? Silverlight?

Comment: It's a Windows Forms program.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try checking if [DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shorttimepattern.aspx) contains `H`. If it does, the system is using 24-hour time

Comment: Thanks, that looks like the proper approach. But wouldn't it be even more correct to test for just "H"? (Or "HH", but that would be redundant.)

Comment: One other very minor point - I can see you added WinForms as a tag for my question, but isn't my question and your answer independent of the presentation system being used?

Comment: 1) You're right, I edited my answer  2) I did it just because you said you're doing it in Winforms. Not sure if Silverlight and WPF have a different way of doing this.

Comment: what about checking for Contains("t")

Answer (score 3):

Just a small addition if I may. Based on the answer by dario_ramos, I turned this into an extension method with a supporting unit test, which passes on my system (checking 378 cultures).

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static bool Is24Hrs(this CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        return cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern.Contains("H");
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class DateTimeExtensionTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Unit_Can_Determine_If_Culture_Uses_24HrTime()
    {
        var cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);
        foreach (var cultureInfo in cultures)
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
            var datetime = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 23, 0, 0);
            var formatted = datetime.ToString("t");
            var is24Hrs = formatted.Contains("23");
            Assert.AreEqual(is24Hrs, cultureInfo.Is24Hrs());
        }
    }
}
```