# Detect time format in Windows time setting i.e 12hr or 24hr and use that in Java

Tags: java, windows, systemtime

I want to know what time format has the user chosen in his computer say in his Windows time setting like 12 hr or 24 hour format. I want to detect that and use that as the time format in my Java application.

Note: I am aware of the SimpleDateFormat API but that is something I will use only after I can detect what user has selected in Windows time setting.

Any help is appreciated.
Krishna

Comment: Same question but for Ruby: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19144045. And for iOS: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1972108

Answer (score 0):

For [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), You call [toLocalizedPattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#toLocalizedPattern--)()

For Java 8 users:

The Java 8 Date Time API is similar to Joda-time. To gain a localized pattern we can use class [DateTimeFormatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.MEDIUM);
```

Note that when you call toString() on LocalDate, you will get date in format ISO-8601

Note that Date Time API in Java 8 is inspired by Joda Time and most solution can be based on questions related to time.

Comment: The solution you provided gives only the format used in the Locale. Here is what I did that worked for me -
`ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "time");
 builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
 Process p = builder.start();
 InputStream inputStream = p.getInputStream();
 BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(
 new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
 String line = null;
 while ( (line = r.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
    p.destroy();
  }`

This prints 
The current time is: 19:16:07.43
Enter the new time: 
For 24H format

Comment: The [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIME_(command)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIME_(command)) has all the details which can be used to detect the time format in different OS and looked up to feed our Java Application logic